# Can anyone draft up some code to recursively search binary tree for a target and return that?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

Here's a method header but I'm really confused

```
public TreeNode find(Treenode Target){

}
```

Heres something I was trying. Can anyone critique, fix this

```
public TreeNode find(Treenode Target){
    treeNode targ = null;

    if(this.getdata == target)
        return this;

    if(left != null)
        targ = left.find(target);

    if(right != null)
        targ = right.find(target);

    return targ;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this method... You are trying to search for the parameter. Maybe this should be named `contains` and return a boolean instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt should stop the recursing at the point a target is found. In your formulation, even if the target is found on the `left`, it will continue recursing down the `right`. Your pseudocode syntax is a little jarbled, but if I follow the gist:

```
public TreeNode find (TreeNode target) {
    TreeNode targ = null;

    if (getdata() == target.getdata())
        return this;

    if (left() != null)
        targ = left().find(target);

    if (targ == null && right() != null)
        targ = right().find(target);

    return targ;
}
```

If your binary tree is organized as a binary search tree, you can avoid the exhaustive search of the data structure, and only follow the side that would contain your item if the item is in your tree.

```
public TreeNode find (TreeNode target) {
    TreeNode next;

    if (getdata() == target.getdata())
        return this;

    if (getdata() < target.getdata())
        next = left();
    else
        next = right();

    return (next != null)
               ? next.find(target)
               : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check what the recursive search returns, something like:

```
public TreeNode find(Treenode Target){
    treeNode targ = null;

    if(this.getdata == target)
        return this;

    if(left != null) {
        targ = left.find(target);
        if (targ!=null)
            return targ;
        }

    if(right != null)
        targ = right.find(target);
        if (targ!=null)
            return targ;
        }

    return null;
}
```

You can spare the last `if` and `return targ` an the end, but I think this is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Following is your code shortened:

```
public TreeNode find(Treenode target) {
    TreeNode targ = null;
    if(this.getdata == target) return this;
    if(left != null) targ = left.find(target);
    if(right != null) targ = right.find(target);
    return targ;
}
```

Your code will fail in the case when the target is in the left subtree because you are not checking the value returned from the call `left.find(target)`. The variable `targ` may have a valid value after that call but it will get overwritten by the call to `right.find(target)` which you make when right subtree is not empty.

The correct code can be:

```
public TreeNode find(Treenode target) {
    if(this == target) return this; //return if I'm the node being searched
    TreeNode targ = null;
    if(left != null) targ = left.find(target); //first search in my left subtree
    if(targ != null) return targ; //if found in my left subtree, return the node
    if(right != null) targ = right.find(target); //search in my right subtree
    return targ; //just return - whether null or a valid node
}
```